# Finding whether a directed graph G contains a color alternating cycle in linear time using DFS

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

after a tutorial about DFS I was handed the question above.

Edges are colored in one of two colors.

A color alternating cycle is a cycle where each pair of neighboring edges are not colored with the same color.

Finding a solution in O(|V|^2+|V||E|) is not complicated but I am not able to improve it.

Checking whether a graph contains a cycle can be done in linear time using DFS but I have no idea how to actually locate the cycle.

I am trying to find a property that will be easier to check because obviously going through every single cycle is not possible.

The only stuff I have learned so far are BFS and DFS.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could make a new directed graph containing $2n$ nodes, such that if there was an edge between node $i$ and $j$, you can connect $i$ to $j+n$ and $j$ to $i+n$ if it's red, or $i+n$ to $j$ and $j+n$ to $i$ if it's blue. Then find a cycle in this graph. This graph forces you to use red and blue alternatively, and no red-blue cycles are lost. The intuition is $i+n$ denotes red used last and reached node $i$, and $i$ denotes blue used last, and reached node $i$. It doesn't really matter for the first one though.

Comment: @adityajain. I thought about that exactly but forgot I could find any cycle in linear time. Thanks.